I would like to get the maximum number of concurrent connections for archived live streams using peakConcurrentViewers Metrics, etc

Component

YouTube Analytics API

Description

I am using the YouTube Analytics API to retrieve the peakConcurrentViewers metric. I need to confirm if this metric can be obtained for archived live streams. I receive a 403 Forbidden error when attempting to retrieve this data.

Scope

openid
profile
email
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/yt-analytics.readonly
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube


API request with parameters used


GET https://youtubeanalytics.googleapis.com/v2/reports?ids=channel==MINE&metrics=peakConcurrentViewers&filters=video==-1aevWQtSZk&startDate=2024-06-01&endDate=2024-06-30


Result

{
  error: {
    code: 403, 
    message: 'Forbidden', 
    errors: [ { message: 'Forbidden', domain: 'global', reason: 'forbidden' } ] 
  }
}



Expected result

{
    "kind": "youtubeAnalytics#resultTable",
    "columnHeaders": [
        {
            "name": "peakConcurrentViewers",
            "columnType": "METRIC",
            "dataType": "INTEGER"
        }
    ],
    "rows": [
        [
            100
        ]
    ]
}


Incidentally, if peakConcurrentViewers is changed to views, the response is returned correctly


Is it 100% reproducible?

Yes, it occurs every time.

Reproducible API explorer link

https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtubeAnalytics/v2/youtubeAnalytics.reports.query?ids=channel==MINE&metrics=peakConcurrentViewers&filters=video==-1aevWQtSZk&startDate=2024-06-01&endDate=2024-06-30

curl \
  'https://youtubeanalytics.googleapis.com/v2/reports?endDate=2024-06-30&filters=video%3D%3D-1aevWQtSZk&ids=channel%3D%3DMINE&metrics=peakConcurrentViewers&startDate=2024-06-01&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --compressed


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
